# How to load video from emulator internal storage to video player in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

I am new to flutter. i want to create an app to load video from device storage to video player.
I have used Video_player plugin and it works fine when i load video from URL or asset.
but i want to load video from videos that i have in my phone.
below code is for load video from assets

**How can i do this?**

```
ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ChewieListItem(
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
              'videos/video_one.mp4'
            ),
            looping: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use VideoPlayerController.file

example

```
ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ChewieListItem(
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.file(
              filePath
            ),
            looping: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: it's not working giving error.